# Replacement portion of regexp_replace oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a regexp_replace where I want to have the replacement portion to be sub part of the replaced string..
In below example /2 should always give the first part i.e MON
For example

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Test MON 234','^(.*? )(MON|FRI|SAT|SUN).*$', '\1\2') FROM dual;
==> Test MON
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('QA FRI 111','^(.*? )(MON|FRI|SAT|SUN).*$', '\1\2') FROM dual;
should give ==>  QA MON
```

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('QA FRI 111','^(.*? )(MON|FRI|SAT|SUN).*$', '\1 MON') FROM dual;`?

Comment: yes, but i don't want to hardcore as I have many many such expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the trivial answer:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Test MON 234','^(.*? )(MON|FRI|SAT|SUN).*$', '\1MON') FROM dual;
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('QA FRI 111','^(.*? )(MON|FRI|SAT|SUN).*$', '\1MON') FROM dual;
```

the less trivial answer: extract the frozen part of your replacement string from the regexp.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('^(.*? )(MON|FRI|SAT|SUN).*$', '^[^(]*\([^(]*\(([^)|]+).*$', '\1') FROM dual;
```

note the assumptions of this solution:
  - you want precisely the first alternative of the second capture group.
  - no nested capture groups
  - no escaped capture group delimiters

for anything more complicated (in fact, for this use case, too) you might wish to consider obtaining the frozen replacement from whatever source determines that and not by extracting it from the regex pattern. otherwise there will be a code maintenance nightmare ahead for somebody.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot,and ya I got it, it will be a big nightmare for future.